# JMS serialized XmlAttribute with HTML entity &amp;

Tags: symfony, jms-serializer

I use this annotation for property "picture"

```php
@JMS\XmlAttribute()
```

Build result with methods

```php
\JMS\Serializer\SerializerBuilder::create()->build()->serialize($data, 'xml')
```

Object with property $picture value "http ://site.com/?a=1&b=2"
serialized to xml

```xml
<tag picture="http://example.com/?a=1&amp;b=2"
```

How to setup serialize without `&amp;`?
I need simple '&' do not decode & into an HTML entity

Comment: What is the structure of $data?